# Can you use SCSS inside React styled components?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I have been learning CSS, SCSS, etc for a while and I like to use SCSS over regular CSS. BUT have just started to learn React and currently using styled-components.

Am I able to use SCSS and all the features e.g. variables, mixins within React web projects?

Or do I have to use a method of having an external compiled CSS file (from scss) and add it into the head of the HTML file?

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/05/styling-components-react/

Comment: @Will Read this doc at [ https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/ ], I hope this helps l

Comment: I think you have to have an external compiled CSS file